How to combine async functions with callbacks in python?
If I have an async view in Django, can I have it await a callback?
Pseudocode:
async def my_view(request):
    # Use external services that eventually send data to /callback/
    do_something()
    # Wait for the callback
    result = await callback_executed()
    do_something_else(result)

# view for /callback/
def callback(request, result):
    # Here control should be returned to my_view providing the result data

I would like to avoid having to implement the second part of my_view inside callback, but rather have an async function that returns the result in the original view as soon as the callback is executed.

I solved it using redis.
The view my_view polls a redis pubsub queue:
def my_view(request)
    pubsub = redis.pubsub()
    await pubsub.subscribe("some_channel")
    # Use external services that eventually send data to /callback/
    do_something()
    # Wait for the callback
    for _ in range(30):
        message = await pubsub.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
        if message:
            result = message["data"]
            do_something_else(result)
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)

And the callback view publishes in the queue:
def callback(request, result):
    redis.publish("some_channel", result)

